# Mongoose redis caching

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, redis, discord.js

https://medium.com/@haimrait/how-to-add-a-redis-cache-layer-to-mongoose-in-node-js-a9729181ad69

In this guide. So I mostly do queries like

```js
{
id: <guild id>
}
```

so whenever new document is created.

```js
 const book = new Book({
      title,
      content,
      author
    });

    try {
      await book.save();
      clearKey(Book.collection.collectionName);
      res.send(book);
    } catch (err) {
      res.send(400, err);
    }
```

will it remove stuff from caches if i use {id: } or will it delete only data on cache that is like empty object or like Model#find()?

I also have another problem which is not related to that but could ask.
Imagine I do this

```js
const result = Model.findOne()

Cache.set(<anything>, JSON.stringify(result));
```

```js
const cached = Cache.get(<anything>)
const result = new Model(cached);

result.message++;

await result.save().catch(console.error)
```

it throws the MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:
How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearKey(Book.collection.collectionName)` In short, it will clear all the cache for the collection.

---

#### TLDR

In your case `this.hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || this.mongooseCollection.name);` is `collectionName`

---

https://redis.io/commands/hget

> Returns the value associated with field in the hash stored at key.

```
clearKey(hashKey) {
    client.del(JSON.stringify(hashKey));
}
```

https://redis.io/commands/del

> Removes the specified keys. A key is ignored if it does not exist.

So when you call `clearKey(Book.collection.collectionName);` it calls `client.del` which will delete all the records for that particular collection. as the complete hash is deleted.

---

To delete specific fields not the full hash :-

https://redis.io/commands/HDEL

> Removes the specified fields from the hash stored at key. Specified fields that do not exist within this hash are ignored. If key does not exist, it is treated as an empty hash and this command returns 0.

Comment: what if a document is deleted. And it still is in redis cache?

Comment: you'll get the document from the cache, which is very bad !! That's why `invalidating caches` is very important.

Comment: Oh. Can I get a example on invalidating caches?

Comment: Hey one last help. So when i do <Model>.findOne().cache() and try to change something and use save it gives the dupe key error. How do i fix that?

Comment: @IshitiaqNaserUthsho When you get the document from the cache it's JSON data, not the actual model object  You can use https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html or https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate instead of save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library, which has event-based logic to clear cache if some related changes appear. It also has an option to pass a custom callback to check, if your record was marked as deleted, but not physically removed from database.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/speedgoose